# sqlite query over two tables related by many-to-many table, with duplicates on one table

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have 2 tables:

```
Attendee(AttendeeId integer PRIMARY KEY, LastName, FirstName, etc...)
Company(CompanyId integer PRIMARY KEY, CompanyName, etc ...)
```

and a many-to-many relation over them:

```
CompanyAttendeeRelation
(
    CompanyId integer REFERENCES Company (CompanyId),
    AttendeeId integer REFERENCES Attendee (AttendeeId),
    PRIMARY KEY (CompanyId, AttendeeId)
);
```

So, from the above, a company can have more than one attendee and an attendee can be in more than one company.

However, I've tried, for instance:

```
SELECT   (LastName || " " || FirstName) as AttendeeName,  
         CompanyAttendeeRelation.AttendeeId, 
         CompanyAttendeeRelation.CompanyId 

FROM     Attendee join CompanyAttendeeRelation on CompanyAttendeeRelation.AttendeeId = Attendee.AttendeeId join Company on CompanyAttendeeRelation.CompanyId = Company.CompanyId 

GROUP BY LastName;
```

But I don't get all companies for an attendee. That is, for instance, say an attendee with `AttendeeId = 15` has a company with `CompanyId = 20` and another with `CompanyId = 100`, I'd expect to get:

```
Doe John|15|20

Doe John|15|100
```

But I'm only getting:

```
Doe John|15|100
```

So I'm not sure if it is the `JOIN` that stops on the first match and the second one never gets computed or if somewhere duplicates (in this case for AttendeeId) are getting ignored.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want all the combinations, why would you `GROUP BY`? Try it without.

```
SELECT (LastName || " " || FirstName) as AttendeeName,  
       CompanyAttendeeRelation.AttendeeId, 
       CompanyAttendeeRelation.CompanyId 

FROM   Attendee
JOIN   CompanyAttendeeRelation ON CompanyAttendeeRelation.AttendeeId = Attendee.AttendeeId
JOIN   Company on CompanyAttendeeRelation.CompanyId = Company.CompanyId; 
-- GROUP  BY LastName;
```

Better yet, for this particular query, you don't need to join `Company` at all. So try this:

```
SELECT (LastName || " " || FirstName) as AttendeeName,  
       CompanyAttendeeRelation.AttendeeId, 
       CompanyAttendeeRelation.CompanyId 

FROM   Attendee
JOIN   CompanyAttendeeRelation ON CompanyAttendeeRelation.AttendeeId = Attendee.AttendeeId;
```

Comment: I meant "ORDER BY"... great. hehe.

Comment: Now, on a related note, how would I go about combining the CompanyId's into a single column in the resulting table? That is, using ORDER BY (and not GROUP by) I get in the example I gave:Doe John|15|20. I'll actually end up using the CompanyName's for that, but you get the point.

Doe John|15|100. Now let's say I want to end up with Doe John|15|100 20|

Comment: @SaldaVonSchwartz: cool, that one's solved. For your new question it is better to edit your question or create a new question for better readability. You can always link to this one to make things clear and save yourself redundant typing.